# Combinatorics Summation

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Let n be an even natural number.

It is required to derive/prove that:

nC1-nC2+nC3-nC4.......+nC(n/2)-........+nC(n-1)=2

(I stumbled upon this while trying to derive the formula for no. of derangements given in my textbook on my own. I checked it on the calculator  for many numberes and it is true all the time.

I have no clue how to proceed to prove this so please help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lefthand side is the number of odd-sized subsets of $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ minus the number of even-sized non-empty, proper subsets of $[n]$. Provided that $n\ge 2$, $[n]$ has the same number of odd-sized subsets as it has even-sized subsets. If you know this, you can simply observe that the lefthand side excludes the even-sized subsets $\varnothing$ and $[n]$, and the result follows immediately.

You can prove the result about even- and odd-sized subsets of $[n]$ by induction on $n$ or by applying the binomial theorem to $(-1+1)^n$.

Comment: This was really helpful, solved my problem. I am obliged to thank you. I just had to do a bit of research for a concrete proof of the first para. of your answer (no. of odd subsets=no. of  even subsets), but its fine , now I have got it.

Comment: @saitama: You’re welcome; I’m glad that it helped.